# make raspberry appear as SSID

Tags: raspberry-pi, ssid

I have a nodejs server in my raspberry and I want people to be able to connecto to it just connecting to the raspi.

The ideal scenario is where in my phone I see the raspi SSID, I connect to it. Then I open chrome enter the ip:port of the raspi itself and it works. Nothing fancier.

What I don't know how to search for in the internet is how to set my pi in a way that it opens itself to the world and appears in the SSID list in my phone. I don't need internet sharing nor anything. Just accessing the nodejs server in the pi.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved depending on the OS you are using in your pi. Use basically need to use `hostapd` and a `DHCP Server`.

You can use a script like [create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

Comment: Im using raspbian